# ¿Como solucionar el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax;?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Estoy realizando una tabla donde tengo que editar las actividades registradas pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursophp\sp_editar_act.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cursophp\sp_editar_act.php(11): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'UPDATE activida...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursophp\sp_editar_act.php on line 11

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
    include 'conexion_miniproyecto.php';
    $id = $_POST['id'] ;
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'] ;
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'] ;
    $realizadas = $_POST['realizadas'] ;
    
    $sql_editar = "UPDATE actividades SET fecha='$fecha',descripcion='$descripcion',realizadas='$realizadas' WHERE id=$id";
    
    $seleccion = mysqli_query($con, $sql_editar);
    
    if(!$seleccion){
        echo "No se Actualizo!!!";
    }
    else{
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

Ya intenté, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Alguien podría ayudarme, por favor.

Comment: Hola, podrías editar la pregunta y compartirnos el contenido del archivo `conexion_miniproyecto.php`. Si hay algún host y/o contraseña sensible, le pones cualquier otra cosa.

Comment: Prueba concatenando las variables en lugar de pasarlas directamente, algo así por ejemplo: `$sql_editar = "UPDATE actividades SET fecha='".$fecha."', descripcion='".$descripcion."', realizadas='".$realizadas."' WHERE id=".$id." ";`

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero revises la variable fecha (como la estas manejando como string) que esté siendo recibida en formato YYYY-MM-DD (año-mes-día).

Comment: Por el mensaje de error, diría que no estas enviando el `id`. Utilizá la opción [edit] y  agregar el resultado de hacer `var_export($_POST); die();`

Comment: @DjCrazy esto no debería tener ningún problema **desde el punto de vista sintáctico**: `"UPDATE actividades SET fecha='$fecha',descripcion='$descripcion',realizadas='$realizadas' WHERE id=$id"` si todas las variables son correctas. Incluso es un código más limpio que las concatenaciones con `.`. Evidentemente los problemas en este código son varios, traté de abordarlos en la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

El principal problema aquí es lo que yo llamo *programación optimista o ingenua*. Consiste en programar ignorando el control de errores, pensando que todo irá bien. O, suponiendo la buena intención de todos los usuarios. Pero, un usuario mal intencionado podría usar un código así para atacar a tu sistema, y ese ataque puede ser de cualquier tipo. Aquí el riesgo está presente en forma de *inyección SQL* y deberías prevenirlo usando consultas preparadas.

Por otra parte, es necesario controlar el estado de las cosas para escribir un programa sólido. No tiene por qué haber conexión, las variables el `$_POST` no tienen por qué estar ahí, etc.

Finalmente, en consultas del tipo `UPDATE`, `INSERT` o `DELETE` la verificación de `query()` no basta para saber si ocurrió algo **efectivamente**. Supongamos una consulta correcta desde el punto de vista sintáctico, pero que no encuentra filas porque el criterio `WHERE` no se cumple. En ese caso `query()` devolverá `true`, y asumirás que se actualizó una o más filas, pero NO se actualizó nada realmente, porque ninguna fila cumpliá el criterio. La propiedad que debes verificar para este tipo de consultas es `affected_rows`.

Aplicando lo dicho propongo lo siguiente:

### Activar el modo de Exception en la conexión

Para ello, modifica tu conexión en el archivo `conexion_miniproyecto.php` **dejando sólo la conexión**:

```
# Cambia las credenciales por las tuyas
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

$con->set_charset('utf8');

# Nada más aquí de mysqli_connect_errno ni historias
```

Y agregando lo siguiente, para activar el manejo de excepciones:

```
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;
```

Si en la conexión te pones a revisar  `mysqli_connect_errno` y haces un `echo` o un `die`, esto no sirve para nada más que para romper el flujo en contextos en que esperas una respuesta estructurada por ejemplo. Es mejor verificar el estado de `$con` en cada contexto antes de usarlo y adaptar la no conexión a ese contexto, haciendo un `echo` o creando un mensaje en un array en casos de que esperas un retorno de datos.

Ahora vamos al código del `UPDATE`:

```
<?php
    $id = !empty($_POST['id']) ?? NULL;
    if ($id) 
    {
        try
        {
            include 'conexion_miniproyecto.php';
            $fecha = $_POST['fecha'] ?? NULL;
            $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'] ?? NULL;
            $realizadas = $_POST['realizadas'] ?? NULL;
    
            $sql_editar = "UPDATE actividades SET fecha=?,descripcion=?,realizadas=? WHERE id=?";    
            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql_editar);
            $stmt->bind_param('sssi', $fecha, $descripcion, $realizadas, $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            printf("Filas actualizadas: %d",$stmt->affected_rows);
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
        catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) 
        {
            # Conviene quizá redirección de error
            echo $e->__toString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        # Conviene quizá redirección de error
        echo "El ID es nulo o vacío";
    }   
?>
```

En la lógica yo he condicionado la ejecución de la consulta a que el valor de `$id` no sea nulo, como es natural, porque es el criterio del `WHERE`. Pero si algunas de las columnas ahí implicadas tienen restricción `NOT NULL` en la tabla, debes incluirlas en esa verificación, declarándolas antes del `if` e incluyéndolas en la verificación.

Por ejemplo, si la fecha debe ser `NOT NULL`:

```
    $id = !empty($_POST['id']) ?? NULL;
    $fecha = !empty($_POST['fecha']) ?? NULL;

    if ($id && $fecha) 
    {
        try
        {
            include 'conexion_miniproyecto.php';
            # Aquí ya no declaras $fecha
            $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'] ?? NULL;
            $realizadas = $_POST['realizadas'] ?? NULL;
```

Con esto tu código debería funcionar, salvo otros errores. Si no entiendes algo pregunta en comentarios al pie de esta respuesta. **Soy humano, no soy una IA**.